# Say ABCDE is a pentagon. Is "ABCDE" the name of this pentagon?

Tags: word-request, mathematics

This could be the start of a maths' exercise: "ABCDE is a pentagon."

In french, we would say "nom" (name) of the polygon to refer to "ABCDE", while "nature" of the polygon would refer to "pentagon".

Reading wikipedia, I figured out that, in english, "pentagon" is the *name* of this polygon. So, what is "ABCDE"? Is it possible to call it the name of the polygon, too, or is there any specific word?

**Some context:** I need a correct english word that I can use as a variable name in a software I develop, in order to store, for instance, the string "ABCDE" as a polygon's property whose name would be understood by anyone. For instance, if I write `polygon.name`, I guess anyone would guess it stores something like "triangle" or "pentagon" etc. Now it's about this "ABCDE": I cannot store it in `polygon.name` too. So, `polygon.????`?

Comment: The pentagon is the name of the shape; ABCDE is the name of a specific pentagon.

Comment: I haven't (yet) voted to close this question, but I still might. I don't think ELL is here to help with the naming of elements in software, which often involve entities and relationships that we rarely need to refer to in natural speech. To be honest, your context looks like one where I'd probably just assign each specific instance of a pentagon a ***Unique ID*** (and I might or might not code "pentagon" as a derived subclass inheriting as much as possible from class::polygon).

Comment: It is really just a *path* that describes the pentagon (although I do not know the mathematical term for it). BCDEA also describes the same pentagon, as does EDCBA. The same pentagon can be described by 10 different paths. For that reason, I would hesitate to call ABCDE a *name*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about naming software elements

Comment: This question is probably more suitable for [math.se].

Comment: At the moment, I need an answer for this specific context, but I expected the answer to be the same in an everyday context (I mean, for instance during a maths lesson for pupils). I don't know if math vocabulary questions better fit in [Mathematic](https://math.stackexchange.com/), but if so, feel free to migrate it. Or maybe there: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: VTC for same reason as FF. As a suggestion, though, how about `polygon.sides_count` (since if you end up with a polygon with more than 12 sides, there won't even be a common 'name' for it) and `polygon.vertices`?

Comment: @ThePhoton Well I need to write it in a wording, like "Say ABCDE is a pentagon..."; "pentagon" is stored in `polygon.name`... "ABCDE", maybe in `polygon.vertices_names`, then? `polygon.path` looks interesting too.

Comment: While this may seem like a "naming" question (which would be off-topic), I think that understanding the different words in English used to describe the "name" of something and the "nature" of something is on-topic. The reason why someone wants to understand a particular aspect of the language shouldn't make the question off-topic. The software naming part of this question (in my opinion) is just context to help the folks answering it understand what is being asked, and not the question itself.

Comment: @Mick -- Your first comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the area of pentagon ABCDE, assuming it is regular and the
>   length of a side is 5cm?

There, "ABCDE" is the name of the pentagon. Notice that the name comes after the noun.

In your version

> ABCDE is a pentagon.

setting aside all typographic issues and treating it as a verbal utterance, ABCDE is like a variable name, comparable to "Assume *x* is an odd number greater than 1000".  *x* is something of a name, a label.

Comment: I'd go for "name" too, then. Actually I finally found examples on web pages like [here](http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/Math/Geometry_obj/polygons.htm) (§naming polygons), [here](https://www.learner.org/courses/learningmath/geometry/session3/part_a/finding.html) or [here](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65227.html).

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description I would say that "pentagon" is the *type* of the polygon in question, and "ABCDE" is the *name* or *label* of that shape. So you should use `polygon.type = pentagon` and `polygon.name = 'ABCDE'`.